# Automation Instrument not working with Xcode5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode5

Automation Instrument is working with earlier version of Xcode but not working for Xcode 5.1 ... Is there any other way or work around?

1. Open Xcode project.
2. go To Product Tab
3. select Profile option
4. select Automation template.
5. Click on Profile. It will show message as "An error occurred while trying to run the script".

Comment: How did you do that can you list out the steps?

Comment: Did you choose the target which is your build?

Comment: 1. Open Xcode project . 2. go To Product Tab 3. select Profile  option 4. select Automation template. 5.  Click on Profile.    It will show message as "An error occurred while trying to run the script".

Comment: Do you want to run automation UI Testing for your application?

Comment: yes , I want to run it for UI testing .. And target is also selected.

Comment: Can you please post more of the error detail?

Comment: Can you post your javascript code?